# Can tags be edited on "merged" questions?

Tags: support

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188/books-for-aspiring-dba) has been merged, and as a result cannot be directly "edited".

I'd like to remove the [books](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) tag from the question since that tag needs to go away.  In my opinion, that tag would be very similar to [databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/databases); it is of limited value and doesn't help define the question.  From help:

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

Can a moderator remove the tag from that question?  Does "merging" a question into another question put the first question into a "limbo" where it is no longer modifiable at all?  I can't even down-vote the question.

Comment: Removed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a moderator remove the tag from that question?

Yes. [bluefeet♦](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9003/bluefeet) has done that for you on this occasion. If you find a merged question that needs to be edited, flag it as Other... and describe what should be done.

> Does "merging" a question into another question put the first question into a "limbo" where it is no longer modifiable at all? I can't even down-vote the question.

The question stub is closed and [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/194636), so it cannot accept:

- edits
- up-votes, down-votes
- comments, comment up-votes
- new answers
- reopen votes

from non-moderators.